# Sizes attribute does not work in the image

Tags: html, image, amp-html, srcset

I am trying to change images depending on the screen size, but it doesn't work.

My code

```html
<amp-img alt="description" src="img/picture-large.png" width="675" height="540" layout="responsive" srcset="img/picture-small 565w" sizes="(max-width: 1130px) 50vw, 100vw"></amp-img>
```

I want that from 1130px, selects the small image

Comment: why are you not using CSS for this? just asking

Comment: because it is amp

Comment: so normal css doesn't work on amp?